# Change session ID with cluster redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-session

I have a spring boot project which uses webflux and spring session with redis (cluster mode) for session management.

I am trying to change the session ID when user state changes using

```
webSession.changeSessionId()
```

This results in a `crossslot keys in request don't hash to the same slot` error from `redis`.

How to overcome this issue?

Everything obviously works fine with local standalone redis.

Code to change `session ID`:

```
return Mono.justOrEmpty(sessionObj).flatMap(n -> {

            sessionObj.set... // some change in values

            setSessionAttribute(webSession, servicesSession);

            return webSession.changeSessionId();

        });
```